# Get current Y position of touch events on GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, glsurfaceview, touch-event

In my Application I have a GLSurfaceView where I draw things using OpenGL ES. Now I want the user to be able to touch this GLSurfaceview. Moreover, once the user puts his finger on the view I want to detect the current position on the y axis of the touch event. I am using the following code:

```
 mGLSurfaceView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                Log.d(TAG,motionEvent.getY()+"");
                return false;
            }
        });
```

This works fine, however what I exactly want is that I also get the y postion value while the user swipes up and down on the Surface. Using the code above the `onTouch()` callback gets only called a single time when the user touches the surface.
Is there another Listener I can use for this which I am missing?

In the end I want to implement some scrolling/zooming feature on my GLSurfaceView.

ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured it out on my own.
The Callback gets called not only when the user presses on the view.
However, one has to "filter out" the `MOVE` actions from motion Event.

So here is the working code:

```
 mSurfaceView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

               if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
                Log.d(TAG,"Y:Postion: " + motionEvent.getY());
                return true;
            }
        });
```